# What would be an appropriate data structure for storing URLs that have been visited by a web crawler?

Tags: c#, data-structures, web-crawler

I'm writing a web crawler in C# for my own personal use. It's main purpose will be to download images from the web pages it crawls. Other than the downloaded images it will not save any data from the web page.

I have some logic in place that stores in a list the literal strings of all the URLs visited by the crawler. This is sufficient for short crawling sessions but I imagine that this would start to become a bottleneck in longer sessions when the crawler is doing lookups in a list filled with tens of thousands of URLs. I'm also doing a lookup in my URL queue so that I don't have duplicate URLs in the queue of URLs waiting to be crawled.

My question is in two parts:

1) At the moment I'm not storing any data between crawling sessions, which is fine for now. While the crawler is running, is there a better way to store already visited URLs than a simple list of strings?

2) If I were to start storing data permanently on the disk for multiple session use how would you suggest storing visited URLs in this case?

Comment: A database sounds like a good tool to use here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends very much on how fast your crawler is crawling. If you have a single-threaded crawler then you're not going to do much better on average than one page per second. So you can use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to store the URLs you've visited. Or, if you want to save information about the URLs you've visited, you can use a `Dictionary<string, UrlInfo>`, where `UrlInfo` is a class you define that contains the information you want to keep about each visited URL.

At 86,400 seconds per day, a `HashSet` or `Dictionary` will store quite a few days' worth of data.

But you probably don't want to download the same picture more than once. So you might be better off with what I call an "offline" or "crawl-process-crawl" model. Here's how it works.

When you start the crawl, you visit, say, a few thousand pages that you've identified. You download the pages, extract the links, and write those links to a log file. If you find images, you download and save those. Every page you visit also gets written to a file.

When you're done visiting those pages, you stop the crawler. You now have two lists saved in files: pages that you've visited and links that you've found.

Sort the visited links and merge them with the list of pages you've visited before. That file can become rather large over time.

Sort the list of links that you extracted, and remove duplicates. Then check those links against the list of pages that you've already visited. This is easiest with a merge. If the link has already been visited, discard it. Otherwise, write it to the file that will be used in your next crawling session.

This is easier with a simple database, but be aware that the database will become very large. With the database you don't have to crawl-process-crawl. Instead, you can check each link that you extract against the database and either save or discard it immediately.

Understand, though, that you'll be hitting the database pretty hard. My experience with crawling is that, on average, a Web page contains over 100 links (that is `<a href="...">`. That doesn't include images. You're going to be hitting that database at least 100 times per second with a single-threaded crawler.

Another problem you'll encounter is that you can't visit every URL you find. Over time, I found that of those 100 links I extract from the average Web page, 10 of them are new links that I've never seen before. So for every page I read, I find 10 more pages that I haven't read. Eventually you'll need some way to filter out the URLs that aren't likely to lead you to images.

Another possibility for keeping track of the URLs that you've visited is to use a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). I used those to great effect in my Web crawler.

Comment: Thanks for the input. If it makes any difference my crawler is multithreaded. Also, what would go into the string portion of the dictionary?

Comment: @DavidDeMar: The URL would go into the `string` (the key) of the dictionary. If your crawler is multithreaded, you'll need some kind of synchronization on your dictionary (a lock, for example) to prevent corrupting it with concurrent updates. You'll also have to multiply my estimates above by the number of threads. A database is looking like a better approach.